# Meteor: ReactMeteorData with Ecmascript6

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am developing an application using Meteor and ReactJS.  I am using the ES6 syntax for my React components.  With the old syntax, you could do something like this:

```
MyComponent = React.createClass({
   mixins: [ReactMeteorData],

   render() {
    ...
   }
})
```

But how would this transfer over to ES6 syntax?

Help appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refer to "ES6 syntax", do you mean creating React components with ES6 classes? Like the codes below:

```
class HelloMessage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
}
```

Unfortuantely, there's no mixin support if you create React components with ES6 classes. You must use the `React.createClass` way.

The following is from React official documentation: [Reusable Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-mixins):

> #### No Mixins
>
> Unfortunately, ES6 launched without any mixin support. Therefore, there is no support for mixins when you use React with ES6 classes. Instead, we're working on making it easier to support such use cases without resorting to mixins.

Answer (score 1):

Id check out the following: 
https://github.com/brigand/react-mixin

It allows for you to use mixins as decorators on ES6 classes:

```
@ReactMixin.decorate(ReactMeteorData)
export default class MyClass extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

Comment: This won't work as decorators are ES7 and meteor by default does not support decorator. The best approach would be to use react-mix like 

reactMixin.class(NameOfClass, ReactMeteorData)